# Removing Characters in a String with Characters from a List

Tags: python

```
def replace_chars(stringa, listb):
    '''A function to return stringa by removing the list of characters from listb'''
    #print(stringa)
    #print(listb)
    for x in stringa:
        if x == listb:
            stringa.replace(x,listb)
    return stringa
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import test
    test.testEqual(replace_chars(" My!Name*Is#John*",["!", "*", "#", "*"]), " My Name Is John ")
```

Basically, I'm supposed to have the characters from the list be taken out of the string like in the test. I'm unsure why this isn't working any help would be greatly appreciated. I need it as a function like this so I can import it into other files.

Thank you for your time

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, it's just not removing the characters and just leaving it the same. Like this "My!Name*Is#John*"

Comment: Replace `if x == listb` to `if x in listb` and `stringa.replace(x,'')`

Comment: Just tried this, I'm still getting the same output where nothing is being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
def replace_chars(stringa, listb):
    '''A function to return stringa by removing the list of characters from listb'''
    #print(stringa)
    #print(listb)
    for x in listb:
        stringa = stringa.replace(x,' ')
    return stringa
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import test
    print(replace_chars(" My!Name*Is#John*",["!", "*", "#", "*"]))
```